# House Price Data in UK by LSOA

Tags: data-request, uk

I'm looking to get average house price data (more realistically, this will probably be data for house sales) by the Lower Super Output Area in the UK

Alternatively, getting it by postcode could work as I could cross reference that to the LSOA.

Would anyone know of a source for this type of data that is easily accessible (i.e. not having to search for each individual Post Code area to get the list and then joining)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to Steven Lee's answer, the *entire* transaction level dataset from England's Land Registry can be downloaded from the [Land Registry site](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/price-paid-data-downloads).

This dataset contains *every* house price from house sales since 1995 and contains both the full postcode, the street name and the street number. If you can handle the entire dataset (~20 million rows) it is not immensely hard to aggregate to LSOA (at least approximately even though postcodes don't map neatly onto LSOAs). An exact mapping might be possible with a little GIS wizardry but the approximate mapping is available using the postcode to LSOA lookups from The [census service here](https://census.edina.ac.uk/pcluts_download.html?data=pcluts_2015nov). The tables provide lookups to most higher-level geographies from full postcodes.

The datasets are a little large to handle in Excel or Access (there are >2 million postcodes never mind the 20m house prices) so it is worth looking for better tools to process them. My personal choice is Google's BigQuery which is designed for large analytical workloads but is cheap (and for small workloads, free) and available to anyone with a web browser and a Google account.

Comment: This feels like the answer, but I'm just checking the data is what I need. Unfortunately the file is 4GB and the Virtual Machine I use at work only has 600MB of spare disk space available (ridiculous I know!) so it cannot open the file... once I have that sorted, I can check on this and confirm the answer!

Comment: @gallus 600MB of free disk space is just a way of saying you have **no** free disk space. ;-) Seriously, though, you are probably someone who could benefit from a cloud based datastore for your bigdata problems. That way you can store everything important online and you just need to be able to have enough space to get the files online to start with.

Comment: That is the plan, although I think we're having it in a local Data Warehouse... It was just a case of checking the data over before loading it into the database to look at data types etc. I'm pretty sure this is what we'll use going forward, or maybe a sub-set of it to make it more recent...

Comment: @gallus The LandRegistry releases update files every month (which are much smaller but are in the same format). You could test ideas on these and use them to keep the full file up to date.

Answer (score 5):

Office for National Statistics have aggregated land registry data to LSOA for you in the [House price statistics for small areas in England and Wales](https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/housing/bulletins/housepricestatisticsforsmallareas/yearendingdecember2017) report.

Disclaimer: I work for the ONS.

Answer (score 3):

http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ppd/

You may already know about this but if not it could get you started? Don't think you can go down to LSOA but you can do postcodes and Counties.  May be other options available too.