# UK house prices including latitude & longitude

Tags: data-request, uk, real-estate

I am aware of the question [House Price Data in UK by LSOA](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/house-price-data-in-uk-by-lsoa).

While it does have some excellent answers, their granularity is postcode.

That is actually good enough for me, but I need to be able to correlate each house sale price with a latitude & longitude (a bonus for additional data, such as number of rooms/square footage, garage, detached, semi-detached, flats, etc - but I really only need price and lat/long).

I started with the governments data for [last month's house sales](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistical-data-sets/price-paid-data-downloads), of which there were more than 65,000 in the UK in September.

I tried using an Open Street Map NOMI API to get lat/long from post code. But, 65k requests blew the 30 second limit on a PHP script.I suppose that I could pause between requests, or offload that part to the client side & build my map gradually, but that might take 5 or 10 minutes :-(  and that's only for a single month.

So, short story long, I am looking for a data source that has already done the conversion and can provide me with sale price + lat/long for UK house sales, preferably a month at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I will not accept this, my own answer, in case someone comes up with a better solution.

However, https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm allows one to download data to map UK post codes to lat/long (no other data, but that is enough for me) as MSsql, MySql or CSV format.

If I download it once, then I don't need the overhead of an HTTP API call for each of those 65k house prices.